# Using MySQL how do I select data between two dates if the dates are in separate columns

Tags: mysql, date

In my database, I have a column with a check-in date and a column with a check-out date. I need to select every row that has a check-in date <= 7/30/2017 and a check-out date that is >= 7/30/2017.

This is the code I have now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `v_reservation_records` 
WHERE cast(checkin as date) <= '7/30/2017' 
AND cast(checkout as date) >= '7/30/2017'
```

Here is an example date from the DB:

```
2018-09-18
```

When I run this query, I do not get any results, but I know that I have a check-in date equal to 7/30/2017. What am I missing? Or is there an easier way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: The data type is date.

Comment: Then just use `'2017-07-30'` instead of `'7/30/2017'`. And don't cast date to date.

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM v_reservation_records 
WHERE checkin <= '2017-30-7'
AND checkout >= '2017-30-7'`

Comment: Running this still returns no results. If you're right though, it looks like I have a formatting problem instead of a coding problem. :)

Comment: If it still doesn't work, post some sample data (with CREATE and INSERT statements) which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are casting valid values for date
You should convert also the literal the date properly

```
SELECT * 
FROM `v_reservation_records` 
WHERE cast(checkin as date) <= str_to_date('7/30/2017' , '%d/%m/%Y')
AND cast(checkout as date) >= str_to_date('7/30/2017' , '%d/%m/%Y')
```

and you can also use between

```
SELECT * 
FROM `v_reservation_records` 
WHERE str_to_date('7/30/2017','%d/%m/%Y') 
        between cast(checkin as date) AND cast(checkout as date)
```

Comment: It turns out that your second answer solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Spiegel, thanks for your troubleshooting as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `v_reservation_records` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(checkin, '%m/%d/%Y') between '7/30/2017' 
AND '7/30/2017'
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, because it spoils the possibility of using an index. Just use date values in the canonical YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: This would not work because the check out date is not guaranteed to be the date that I'm searching for.